# C++ no output to the console, no compile error

Tags: c++, io, console, output

I have the following code that presents no errors when compiled. I have tried numerous suggestions from answers on other questions and my issue persists: when I compile by typing "g++ hello world.cpp -o helloworld" I have no errors compiling but nothing displays to the console. I am a complete beginner. What is the issue here?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried executing?

Comment: Run the program that you created.  All you did was `build` the program.

Comment: You need to choose one of the beginner books from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list and have a good read.

Answer (score 4):

g++ hello world.cpp -o helloworld" compiles the code, it does not execute it.

Execute it with :
./helloworld

(make sure that you have the permissions to do so)